# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, func

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpress in my localhost server.I am creating custom menu. But when i tried to remove existing "primary" menu from it, this Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'tnc-remove_default_menu' not found or invalid function name in F:\AppServ\www\itexperthouseen\wp-includes\comment-template.php 
showed up on my admin page. can anyone solve this problem??!!

Thanks,

My comments.php code is :-

```
        <div id="comments">
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) : ?>
                <p class="nopassword"><?php _e( 'This post is password protected. Enter the password to view any comments.', 'tie' ); ?></p>
            </div><!-- #comments -->
<?php
        return;
    endif;
?>

<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
            <h3 id="comments-title">
            <?php comments_number(__('No comments','tie'), __('One comment','tie'), '% '.__('comments','tie') );?>
            </h3>

<?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :  ?>
            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older Comments', 'tie' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'tie' ) ); ?></div>
            </div> <!-- .navigation -->
<?php endif; ?>
            <?php $comments_by_type = &separate_comments($comments); ?>
            <?php if ( !empty($comments_by_type['comment']) ) : ?>
                <ol class="commentlist"><?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=custom_comments'); ?></ol>
            <?php endif; ?>    
            <?php $comment_counter = 0 ; ?>
            <?php if ( !empty($comments_by_type['pings']) ) : ?>
            <div id="pings" class="commentlist">
                <ol class="pinglist"><?php wp_list_comments('type=pings&trackback&pingback&callback=custom_pings'); ?></ol>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?> 
<?php else : 
    if ( ! comments_open() ) :
?>
    <?php __( 'Comments are closed.', 'tie' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php

$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
$req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
$aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

$fields =  array(
    'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'tie' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
    'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'tie' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
    'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website', 'tie' ) . '</label>' .
                '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
);
$required_text = __(' Required fields are marked', 'tie').' <span class="required">*</span>';
?>
<?php comment_form( array(
    'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),
    'must_log_in' => '<p class="must-log-in">' .  sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' , 'tie' ), wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) ) ) . '</p>',
    'logged_in_as' => '<p class="logged-in-as">' . sprintf( __( 'Logged in as <a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>. <a href="%3$s" title="Log out of this account">Log out?</a>'  , 'tie' ), admin_url( 'profile.php' ), $user_identity, wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) ) ) . '</p>',
    'comment_notes_before' => '<p class="comment-notes">' . __( 'Your email address will not be published.'  , 'tie' ) . ( $req ? $required_text : '' ) . '</p>',
    'title_reply' => __( 'Leave a Reply'  , 'tie' ),
    'title_reply_to' => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s'  , 'tie' ),
    'cancel_reply_link' => __( 'Cancel reply'  , 'tie' ),
    'label_submit' => __( 'Post Comment'  , 'tie' )
)); ?>

</div><!-- #comments -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you deleted the function tnc-remove_default_menu when you tried to get rid of the existing primary menu.  So put that code back in and the error should go away.  Then to remove the menu, instead of deleting that function, either remove the hook that's calling that function, or just comment out the code within the function.

Comment: did you put back the function like it was before?